# Symfony 4 : Datatable search filter problem

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I want to make a ticket management system with symfony 4, so I use the 
[Mapsred/TicketingBundle](https://github.com/Mapsred/TicketingBundle) bundle.

This bundle uses to view and search tickets, a table from datatables.net. I am stuck with doctrine on ticket search filters.

I want to be able to search this table for the customer name of the ticket authors

UserEntity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_user")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @AssertPerso\Email
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Formation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $formation;
```

FormationEntity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FormationRepository")
 */
class Formation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $formations = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $customerName;
```

I want to be able to perform in the search tables the column "customerName"

I am stuck in the "TicketRepository" file of the bundle.

TicketRepository:

```
/** @var array $joins */
private $joins;

/**
 * @param string|null $globalSearch
 * @param array $columns
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $sortOrder
 * @param int $offset
 * @param int $limit
 * @param bool $isCount
 * @param string $status
 * @param string $type
 * @param UserInterface|null $user
 * @return array|int
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
 */
public function searchDataTable(string $globalSearch = null, array $columns, array $fields, array $sortOrder, int $offset,
                                int $limit, bool $isCount, $status, $type, UserInterface $user = null)
{
    $this->joins = ['q.status' => 'status'];
    $parameters = ['_status' => $status];
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('status.name = :_status');

    $sort = key($sortOrder);
    $order = $sortOrder[$sort];
    $qb->orderBy($this->getX($sort), $order);

    if ($type === 'perso') {
        $qb->andWhere('q.author = :_author');

        $parameters['_author'] = $user;

    }

    if ($type === 'list_public') {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX('q.author = :_author', 'q.public = :_public'));

        $parameters['_author'] = $user;
        $parameters['_public'] = true;
    }

    if (null !== $globalSearch) {
        $qbWhere = [];
        $parameters['globalSearch'] = '%' . $globalSearch . '%';

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $qbWhere[] = $qb->expr()->like($this->getX($field), ':globalSearch');
        }

        $qb->andWhere(call_user_func_array([$qb->expr(), 'orX'], $qbWhere));
    } elseif (!empty($columns)) {
        $qbWhere = [];
        foreach ($columns as $field => $value) {
            $qbWhere[] = $qb->expr()->like($this->getX($field), ':' . $field);
            $parameters[$field] = '%' . $value . '%';
        }

        $qb->andWhere(call_user_func_array([$qb->expr(), 'andX'], $qbWhere));
    }

    foreach ($this->joins as $join => $alias) {
        $qb->leftJoin($join, $alias);
    }

    $qb->setParameters($parameters);

    if ($isCount) {
        return $qb->select('COUNT(q.id)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    }

    dump($qb);
    return $qb->setFirstResult($offset)->setMaxResults($limit)->getQuery()->getResult();
}

/**
 * @param string $field
 * @return string
 */
private function getX(string $field)
{
    if ($field === 'author') {
        $this->joins['q.author'] = 'author';

        return 'author.username';
    } elseif ($field === 'customername') {
        $this->joins['q.author'] = 'author';

        return 'author.formation';
    } elseif ($field === 'category') {
        $this->joins['q.category'] = 'category';

        return 'category.name';
    } elseif ($field === 'status') {
        $this->joins['q.status'] = 'status';

        return 'status.value';
    } elseif ($field === 'priority') {
        $this->joins['q.priority'] = 'priority';

        return 'priority.value';
    } elseif ($field === 'assignated') {
        $this->joins['q.assignated'] = 'assignated';

        return 'assignated.username';
    }

    return 'q.' . Inflector::camelize($field);
}
```

When I search in a CustomerName field, I get :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 126 near 'formation LIKE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Could someone please help me? I do not understand much about Doctrine, it's pretty new to me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like query is not correct, in full stack trace you should find full query, and next try to run in in database, check validity in IDE that is capable of SQL validation

to see query, attach your breakpoint in:

`\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::executeQuery`

your query should be in `$query` variable